# How to minimize a function over one input parameter in R

Tags: r, minimize

Suppose I have a function that is defined as following

```
myFunction = function(input1, input2, input3) {
    # do something with input and then return
}
```

and now I want to minimize `myFunction` over only the first input, namely, `input1`, while fixing the other parameters.

In R, it seems that there are some prepacked functions like `nlm`, `optim`, etc. But the documentation doesn't really explain how to do the problem above. For example, it seems that `optim` can only minimize a function over only 1 input? I am probably wrong, but please correct me, and show me the advised way of doing this kind of minimizing problem.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For minimizing the output when the input is a vector, you can use `optim`.

```
myFunction = function(input1, input2, input3) sum(abs(input1 - 3))
o = optim(7:10, myFunction, input2=5, input3=6)
o$par
# [1] 2.999989 2.999995 3.000000 3.000001
```

The first argument to `optim` (`7:10` in my example) is the starting value for `input1` (a guess of where to start the optimization). The second is the function, and you can then pass in the fixed parameters (like `input2` and `input3`).

In this example, the minimum turns out to be a vector of only 3s (as that minimizes `sum(abs(input1 - 3))`).

---

If you were performing just a 1-dimensional minimization, you would use the `optimize` function, and pass the other inputs to it after passing the function:

```
myFunction = function(input1, input2, input3) {
    return(abs(input1 - 3) + input2 + input3)
}

o = optimize(myFunction, 2, 3, interval=c(-100, 100))
print(o$minimum)
# [1] 3.000003
```

If you want to minimize based on `input2` or `input3` (one that isn't the first argument to the function), you can give the others as named arguments:

```
myFunction = function(input1, input2, input3) {
    return(abs(input1 - 3) + abs(input2 - 12) + input3)
}

print(optimize(myFunction, input1=2, input3=3, interval=c(-100, 100)))
print(o$minimum)
[1] 11.99998
```

If you're wondering why this is possible, it's because `optimize` is defined as:

```
function (f, interval, ..., lower = min(interval), upper = max(interval), 
          maximum = FALSE, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25)
```

That `...` allows the use of any number of additional parameters that it will then pass to `myFunction`.

Comment: no need for this extra function (currying); you can simply pass the extra arguments through `...`: `o = optimize(myFunction, 2, 3, interval=c(-100, 100))`

Comment: I am sorry one thing I forgot to mention was what should I do if my first argument is a vector? It seems that `optimize()` expects all arguments to be real numbers.

Comment: @Enzo: to be clear, you then want to optimize over the entire vector, as in find the vector of that length that minimizes the output (at which point it is no longer 1d optimization)? Or do you want to run the optimization once for each of the values in that vector?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, it's not a 1d optimization problem. I want to minimize the function over an entire vector, as in minimizing the cost function for a learning algorithm.

Comment: @Enzo: See the update to my answer- I believe the section at the top (using `optim`) is what you want.