# Minimize cost in R

Tags: r, optimization, minimize, minimization

I'd like to minimize the following function

```
cost=function(x){
  events=sum(x==1)
  rev = sum(df$rev[which(x==0)])*0.8

  costcomp1=tail(comp1$cost[which(comp1$Nevents<events)],1)

  costcomp2=tail(comp2$percentuale[which(comp2$k<=rev)],1)*rev+50000

  cost=costcomp1+costcomp2

  return(cost)
}
```

x should be a binary vector, because for every item I want to choose the supplier to buy from

```
head(comp2)
        k percentuale
1  800000      0.0500
2 1800000      0.0325
3 88888888888888      0.0200

head(comp1)
       Nevents  cost
1         1500 13000
2         1750 17000
3         2000 21000
4         2500 22500
5         3000 26000
6         3500 29000
```

I tried `optimize(cost,x)`,`x=sample(c(0,1),nrow(df),replace = T)` but it doesn't work. It gives me the error `invalid function value in 'optimize'`

Comment: How about `optim(cost, x)`? This post looks similar to what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013612/how-to-minimize-a-function-over-one-input-parameter-in-r.

Comment: ```Error in optim(cost, x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
Inoltre: Warning message:
In optim(cost, x) :
  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need might be `fminsearch`

```
pracma::fminsearch
```

and you can try

```
pracma::fminsearch(cost,rep(0,nrow(df)))$fmin
```